# Tarantool Java Connector

Tags: java, database-connection, key-value, tarantool

Do you know a way to connect Java and the [Tarantool](http://tarantool.org/) key/value storage? On the [Tarantool web-site](http://tarantool.org/) I can see connectors for C, Ruby, PHP, etc., but no connector for Java.

I know that Tarantool supports the Memcached protocol (with a lot of Java clients for it), but I need a native Tarantool protocol connector for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is slightly outdated, so I feel that this topic needs an update about the current situation.

There are two Java drivers present for Tarantool as of 2021:

- An "old" [tarantool-java](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java), marked as deprecated, since it does not support vShard cluster, Cartridge, Tarantool 2.x+ features like new `UUID` and `decimal` types, has some problems with API and architecture and is out of maintenance for a long time. However, as of now, it's the one that supports JDBC interface, so you may choose it for connecting to a single Tarantool node via JDBC.
- A "new" [cartridge-java](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-java), which is currently actively developed and maintained, and provides a foundation for other necessary connector modules like [cartridge-springdata](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-springdata) and [cartridge-spark](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-spark). This driver uses [Netty](https://netty.io) for the transport layer, [the official MsgPack library](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java) for serialization, and provides support for single Tarantool nodes, vShard cluster, Cartridge and new Tarantool 2.x+ features. This driver is compatible with 1.10 Tarantol series too.

So, for all cases except JDBC for a single Tarantool node (currently), I'd recommend using `cartridge-java`.

Answer (score 1):

At this point a full-featured driver is ready,  check out http://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java

Comment: I'm waiting for something like JPA implementation for Tarantool. For now, I'm using Amazon SimpleDB and Amazon Dynamo DB, but I want to migrate from these services :) Tarantool seems very good alternative

Comment: There is a new Java connector library in the open since recently: 
https://github.com/dgreenru/tarantool-java